# "Bad Request" response on PredictHQ API ["error": invalid_client] "authentication" request

Tags: ios, swift

Currently looking to make an authentication request on the PredictHQ API using Alamofire.

I have generated client credentials in the developer's console, and transferred them to my project. The problem lies when I use the URL https://api.predicthq.com/oauth2/token/ in my function *receiveJSONData() to receive a network status of my requests.

**Below are examples I followed from the PredictHQ website  https://developer.predicthq.com/oauth2/ on how the cURL request should be formatted as.**

[image] [image]

> 1) I first created my networkServiceClient class

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class networkServiceClient {

    private let token = "GENERATED_TOKEN_FROM_PREDICTHQ_API".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!.base64EncodedString()
    private let secret = "GENERATED_SECRET_KEY_FROM_PREDICTHQ_API".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!.base64EncodedString()
    private let id = "GENERATED_ID_FROM_PREDICTHQ_API".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!.base64EncodedString()
    private let contentType = "application/json"
    private var authURL = URL(string: "https://api.predicthq.com/oauth2/token/")
    private var tokenDataURL = URL(string: "https://api.predicthq.com/v1/events/")

    typealias webResponse = ([[String: Any]]?, Error?) -> Void

    func receiveJSONData(completion: @escaping webResponse){

        let loginString = String(format: "Basic %@:%@", id, secret)

        let postHeaders:HTTPHeaders =  ["Authorization": loginString, "Accept": contentType]

        let params: [String : Any] = ["grant_type": "client_credentials", "scope": "account events signals"]

         //post authentication request
        AF.request(authURL!, method: .post, parameters: params, headers: postHeaders).responseJSON { (response) in

            if let error = response.error {

                completion(nil, error)

            } else if let jsonArray = response.value as? [[String: Any]] {

                completion(jsonArray, nil)

            } else if let jsonDict = response.value as? [String: Any] {

                completion([jsonDict], nil)

            }

        }

}
```

> 2) Then I implemented it in my TestingViewingController

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire


class TestingViewController: UIViewController {

    private let networkingClient = networkServiceClient()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        networkingClient.receiveJSONData() { (json, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else if let json = json {

                print(json.description)
            }

        }

    }

}
```

> 3) Lastly, here is my output in the TestingViewController console.

```
"error": invalid_client
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey it might be because you're base64 encoding the client_id and secret separately but they should be encoded together (separated by colon) like the screenshot shows.

Comment: Thanks rob! Encoding them separate did the job.